# Snapshotting new table SQL Server Debezium Connector

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

Currently I am running Kafka, Zookeper and Debezium inside docker container and SQL server database locally. The whole setup works fine capturing changes as they happen on cdc enabled tables. The initial snapshot of tables also worked.

Question:

1. I want to add tables with existing data inside them to support cdc. Is there a way to snapshot these tables without deleting & registering the connector to again perform initial snapshot?
2. When altering a table is there a better way to update schema than shown here?
   https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-schema-evolution

Thank you for your answers in advance